# Wait for some second then execute button action WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to make button click by wait x second over this button then perform his action, I use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to make that in `Win-form` but how can make the same thing in WPF.
I make this function to wait for 5 second before make some action

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer MTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    private void StartAsyncTimedWork()
    {
        MTimer.Interval = 5000;
        MTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MTimer_Tick);
        MTimer.Start();
    }
```

How i can make the same thing in Wpf and make the user over the button by the mouse and wait for 5 second before perform button action, Can please give me a link or bit of code.

Comment: Thread.Sleep won't do?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan: No, it certainly won't - that will freeze the UI as it will block the  UI thread.

Comment: Actually your code means running `MTimer_Tick` every five seconds.

Comment: [How To Put delay before doing an operation in wpf](http://www.4byte.cn/question/834719/how-to-put-delay-before-doing-an-operation-in-wpf.html)

Comment: @JonSkeet What if we make a separate thread for it and then sleep it?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan: Then you'll need to invoke back to the UI thread to do anything to the UI. I suspect the OP wants to interact with the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative for tmer in windows form the DispatcherTimer control. It does pretty much the same thing, but instead of dropping it on your form, you create and use it exclusively from your Code-behind code.

[The DispatcherTimer](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/dispatchertimer/)

Answer (score 4):

Well you *could* use a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer) instead, but it's probably simplest to use an `async` method and `Task.Delay`:

```
public async void Foo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Observable syntax:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(x => // do something here like 
Console.WriteLine(x));
```